# Postgres breaking null constraint on a serial column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that I create independently, the primary key is set with the serial type and a sequence applied to the table, but when I try to insert a value a NULL CONSTRAINT error is thrown and the return looks like null was passed, am I missing something in the INSERT statement?

SQL for table generation:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public."Team" CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE public."Team" (
    "IdTeam" serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name text NOT null,
    CONSTRAINT "pKeyTeamUnique" UNIQUE ("IdTeam")
);

ALTER TABLE public."Team" OWNER TO postgres;

DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS public."Team_IdTeam_seq" CASCADE;

CREATE SEQUENCE public."Team_IdTeam_seq"
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

ALTER TABLE public."Team_IdTeam_seq" OWNER TO postgres;

ALTER SEQUENCE public."Team_IdTeam_seq" OWNED BY public."Team"."IdTeam";
```

SQL for insert :

```
INSERT INTO public."Team" (name) values ('Manchester Untited');
```

The returning error:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "IdTeam" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Manchester Untited).
SQL state: 23502
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping the sequence causes the default definition for the IdTeam column to be dropped. After recreating the sequence you will have to recreate the default definition.

Comment: Yes, dropping the sequence  and recreating it before dropping the table and creating that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I am baffled.  Why are you trying to define your own sequence when the column is already defined as `serial`?

Second, a primary key constraint is already unique.  There is no need for a separate unique constraint.

Third, quoting identifiers just makes the code harder to write and to read.

You can just do:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.Team CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE public.Team (
    IdTeam serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name text NOT null
);

INSERT INTO public.Team (name) 
    VALUES ('Manchester Untited');
```

Comment: That may be my lack of knowledge, in other tables I used biginteger but I had issues with there being no auto generation on them, changing to serial seemed to answer that, I agree that there is not a requirement for the additional constraint. I will try your suggestion

Comment: @Phil . . . The type is `bigserial`:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL.